# truffle migrate timeout error

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration

I'm only trying to write a simple HelloWorld contract and deploy it to ropsten testnet. When I'm compiling/deploying on Remix i get no issues. However, when i try to run truffle migrate on my project, using infura as my provider, I keep getting this error:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x4242621683eed91b250586b07b929acdb1e88d0e76c057effcd52aa68670b601
- Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0

/[...]/node_modules/request/request.js:816
          var e = new Error('ESOCKETTIMEDOUT')
                  ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
```

What am I doing wrong? Let me know if there's any other info I need to provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/softfair/p/Truffle-migirate-deploy-contract-ESOCKETTIMEDOUT.html), usually, in the module `web3-provider-engine`， modify the `timeout` a bigger number. Remember that, the module maybe imported more than one times, so change the value everywhere in your projects

```
xhr({
    uri: targetUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newPayload),
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    timeout: 2000,  // change the value bigger
```